# Reloading configuration in Elixir (with Mix.Config?)

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

In my config.exs file, I have

```
config :my_app,
  foobar: [%{foo: "bar", keywords: ["hello", "world!"]},
           %{foo: "xyz", keywords: ["bloop"]}]
```

this list is retrieved in the code

```
Application.get_env(:my_app, :foobar)
```

But if I were to update this foobar config, the changes will not take into effect until I restart the application.

Alternatively, is there a better way to go about with this? My original solution parsed a list of lists from a file. It worked great whenever I modified the file, but now I want to work with a list of maps.

Comment: How about storing it as a JSON file? JSON supports maps with string keys. Or you can use `term_to_binary` and `binary_to_term` to store arbitrary terms but they're not human editable directly.

Comment: @Dogbert I went with your first solution -- storing a JSON file and converting it to a Map with Poison.Parser

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any solution that would allow to dynamically reload configuration. It would be hard as configuration flags can influence compilation, for example:

```
defmodule Foo do
  @foo Application.get(:foo, __MODULE__)

  def foo, do: @foo
end
```

In this snippet `@foo` will be computed during compilation.

However you can change configuration using `Application.put_env/3`, but it will affect only runtime fragments.

Answer (score 0):

How do you use the configuration in the code? The change should take place when you use Application.get_env/2 to retrieve the value. Or is it because the config file needs to be recompiled?